# Rails association with multiple custom field names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have `Members` and `Skills` tables.

Each member record has 3 links to a skill: `skill_primary`, `skill_secondary` and `skill_tertiary`.

Each of those columns is just an ID that corresponds to a row in the Skills table.

What I want to be able to do is is reference a members given skill and get that record from the sills table.

So: `member.skill_primary` would return the actual Skill record.

What type of associations would I set up to pull that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to declare 3 `belongs_to` associations and use the `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` options.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill_primary, class_name: 'Skill', foreign_key: :skill_primary
  belongs_to :skill_secondary, class_name: 'Skill', foreign_key: :skill_secondary
  belongs_to :skill_tertiary, class_name: 'Skill', foreign_key: :skill_tertiary
end
```

For documentation on these options, see section 4.1.2 of the Rails Guide for Active Record Associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference